# Rails ActiveRecord: Getting the id of a raw insert

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, octopus

```
sql = DmozCategory.send(:sanitize_sql_array, ["INSERT INTO dmoz_categories (id, dmoz_category_title, dmoz_category_name, dmoz_category_description, created_at, updated_at, dmoz_category_lastupdate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), NOW(), ?)", result['catid'], result['title'], result['name'], result['description'], result['lastupdate']])

res = DmozCategory.connection.execute(sql)
$stderr.puts res.inspect
```

`res` is always `nil`, even though I can see the DmozCategory inserts into the database.  How to get the `id` following my insert?

I realize that I could use another SQL query `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the ID, but I was wondering if there was a way to get the id through Rails.  M

Background: using Rails 2.3.14

**UPDATE**: Hmm, I think the problem lays with a plugin I'm using called [Octopus](https://github.com/tchandy/octopus).  Sorry for discounting some of your answers.. It looks like I need to find how to get the last id of an insert with this plugin.  My complete coe:

```
desc "load all categories from dmoz" # With this one we're loading all the 'structure' table in, not the parent-child relationships.
  task :load_categories_from_dmoz, [ :offset, :limit ] => :environment do |t, args|
    offset = !args[:offset].blank? ? args[:offset].to_i : 0 # Take offset from args.  Default of 0
    limit = !args[:limit].blank? ? args[:limit].to_i : 1 # Take limit from args.  Default of 1
    ActiveRecord::Base.octopus_establish_connection(:adapter=> "mysql", :host=> "localhost", :database => "dmoz", :username => "dmoz", :password => "dmoz")

    results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("SELECT * FROM structure LIMIT #{ offset }, #{ limit }") # Fetches it directly from the dmoz database.
    count = offset
    conn = ActiveRecord::Base.octopus_establish_connection(:adapter=> "mysql", :host=> "localhost", :database => "talon_development", :username => "rails_shadow", :password => "husky")
    results.each do |result|
      if count % 1000 == 0
        puts count
      end
      count +=1

      begin
        sql = DmozCategory.send(:sanitize_sql_array, ["INSERT INTO dmoz_categories (id, dmoz_category_title, dmoz_category_name, dmoz_category_description, created_at, updated_at, dmoz_category_lastupdate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), NOW(), ?)", result['catid'], result['title'], result['name'], result['description'], result['lastupdate']]) #We leave parent_id NULL for the next task to handle relationships

        DmozCategory.connection.execute(sql) #doesn't get the ID..

      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: try `exec_query` and `last_inserted_id(res)`

Comment: @YuriBarbashov I don't think that's available in Rails 2.3.14?

Comment: Aren't you inserting the id yourself? `INSERT INTO dmoz_categories (id, ...) VALUES (?, ...), result['catid'], ...`?

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to check that that's working later on.  Not sure it has been.

Answer (score 14):

In general instead of using `connection.execute`, use `connection.insert`

This will return the generated id of the last inserted row. How it does this is database dependant. On MySQL, the last insert id is a property of the connection. On Postgres a 'returning' clause is appended to the query (with old versions of postgres a fallback asks the sequence for its last id).

Using insert rather than execute also clears the rails query cache.

On MySQL at least, this will work [even if you set the id yourself](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/mysql-insert-id.html).

Comment: How can I get the id?  `DmozCategory.connection.id` and `DmozCategory.connection.last_id` don't seem to have the id i'm inserting

Comment: connection.insert "INSERT ..." should return the id (assuming that your id is a regular auto increment column)

Comment: oh, so I don't need to use `.send` first?  it does both send and execute in one?

Comment: See the question for `.send`, it just gets the SQL.  `DmozCategory.connection.insert(sql)` returns `0`, and `DmozCategory.connection.id` returns `2223123080` even though I can see that it's been inserted into the table with an id of `2`.

Comment: If you happen to be using a Foreign Data Wrapper on PostgreSQL, then calling `#insert` will not automatically use `RETURNING`; however, you can add that the your `INSERT` command that is run on the remote server and it will return the remote id. See [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-insert.html) for examples on `INSERT ... RETURNING`

Answer (score 1):

I think [`insert_sql`](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements/insert_sql) method should help you

```
DmozCategory.connection.insert_sql(sql) # => id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, that is how AR defines id before insert in 2.3

> id = DmozCategory.connection.next_sequence_value(DmozCategory.sequence_name)

Comment: `undefined method `next_sequence_value' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter:0x10d1de1e8>`

Answer (score 0):

If this is the mysql2 gem, and `DmozCategory.connection` is an instance of the client, `DmozCategory.connection.last_id` will work.

Comment: I'm using `mysql`, so `undefined method `last_id' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter:0x106d82d48>`

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the `id` already, can't you just do this?

```
dmoz_category = DmozCategory.find(result['id'])
$stderr.puts dmoz_category.inspect
```

Comment: it's starting to look like this is the only way.  no clue why, but everything else returns either 0 or a huge/wrong number

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using MYSQL and the table auto increments, you could use:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

to do what it says, grab the last inserted ID into the table. This would add another query to your code, but it seems to stick with your using raw SQL.

Comment: would prefer the railsy way of doing this if possible.. is that the only way?

Comment: You could do something like this: `DmozCategory.find(:last).id`

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible, sorry.